# Select latest date (subquery)

Tags: mysql, subquery

For a query I use I want it to output the latest date, however, the table is really mixed. For example purposes I use the following four entries in the table:

[Database Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grgmk.png)

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej9Me.png)

I'm not using the date index for the MatchDate row due to compatability issues. It seems to be working, but when using `MIN()` function in the subquery, it will stop using the `WHERE` filter. I want it to use the filter to show me whatever row is the next to come (what match is next), but it shouldn't be in the past.

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches
WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1
AND MatchDate = (SELECT MatchDate FROM Matches
                 WHERE MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
                 LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `SELECT min(MatchDate) FROM Matches WHERE MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE()` by itself and see what it returns? Also note that you should remove the `LIMIT 1` if you add the `min` function.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in here. It's giving me a NULL result - pretty weird stuff happening.

Comment: Quick adding to this: the CURRENT_DATE() doesn't seem to return anything at all. How would I approach this differently?

Comment: You have `MatchDate` as a text field, have you tried converting it with `DATE(MatchDate) >= CURRENT_DATE()` ?

Comment: My MySQL is giving errors with the CURERNT_DATE() - it seems to be a non-existant function when it's not in a subquery. I currently edited the query to be:
`SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, min(MatchDate) FROM Matches
WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1
AND DATE(MatchDate) >= CURRENT_DATE()
LIMIT 1
GROUP BY ID`

Comment: On a sidenote: A `LIMIT` clause without an `ORDER BY` makes little sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner As I said in my previous comment, the `LIMIT` should be removed because of the `MIN` function anyway

Comment: @ChatterOne: Yes. Sam is littering their queries with `LIMIT` clauses. It would make sense in the original subquery, if it would get ordered by MatchDate descending, though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input: the query now seems to be giving a different error. My Current_Date had to be rewritten as `DATE(CURRENT_DATE())` --> away from that I still get an error when removing the limt (since we're using `MIN`) - it still wants me to group the results (`GROUP BY`) - adding a `GROUP BY` statement only breaks the code even more. Current query: `SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, min(MatchDate) FROM Matches
WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1
AND DATE(MatchDate) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE())`

Comment: @Sam: That last query of seven minutes ago is mere trash. `GROUP BY` applies before `LIMIT`. `GROUP BY id` makes no sense, as ID should be unique in the table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I appreciate your help, however, only coming here to insult the code isn't going to help a single bit. I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it. As you can see in my latest query, there's no `GROUP BY`, or a `LIMIT`.

Comment: @sam Assuming that `DATE(CURRENT_DATE())` gives you the current date (I don't really like it this way), then you probably want something like `SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate >= (SELECT MIN(MatchDate) FROM Matches WHERE DATE(MatchDate) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE()))`

Comment: @ChatterOne - I'm open for suggestions! What would you prefer to do? I'm trying to go for the most optimzed way possible.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes, I was too harsh. I apologize. I've posted an answer. Hope this clears things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches
WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1
AND MatchDate = (SELECT MatchDate FROM Matches
                 WHERE MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
                 LIMIT 1)
LIMIT 1
```

What is this query doing?

1. In the subquery you first select all records with MatchDate > today. From these you take one record (`LIMIT 1`) arbitrarily chosen (no `ORDER BY`).
2. With this future date found you want to select from the table. You have three conditions: `HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate = <some future date>`. You are mixing `AND` and `OR` without using parentheses, so `AND` has precedence over `OR`. This means you have: `HomeTeamID = 1 OR (AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate = <some future date>)`. This may or may not be what you want.
3. From all records matching the conditions, you pick one arbitrarily (again `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY`).

Maybe you want this:

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime 
FROM Matches
WHERE (HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1)
AND MatchDate = (SELECT MatchDate FROM Matches
                 WHERE MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
                 ORDER BY MatchDate
                 LIMIT 1);
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime 
FROM Matches
WHERE (HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1)
AND MatchDate = (SELECT MIN(MatchDate) FROM Matches
                 WHERE MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE());
```

However, this would give you the next date scheduled, no matter what teams are going to play. Then you are looking for a match on that date which team 1 is going to take part in. You may find such match or not.

So maybe you rather want this:

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime 
FROM Matches
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
            FROM Matches
            WHERE (HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1) AND MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
            ORDER BY MatchDate
            LIMIT 1);
```

Which can be written much simpler as

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime 
FROM Matches
WHERE (HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1) AND MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
ORDER BY MatchDate
LIMIT 1;
```

This looks for the team 1 match that lies closest in the future. If no future team 1 match exists, you get no rows returned.

As to your other attempts:

Query 1:

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, min(MatchDate) 
FROM Matches 
WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND DATE(MatchDate) >= CURRENT_DATE() 
LIMIT 1 
GROUP BY ID
```

This should result in an error, but maybe MySQL allows `LIMIT` to be written before `GROUP BY`. You select all records `WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR (AwayTeamID = 1 AND DATE(MatchDate) >= CURRENT_DATE())`. These you group by ID, which does exactly nothing because each record should have a unique ID. Then you select `ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, min(MatchDate)` where `min(MatchDate)` is simply `MatchDate`, because we are looking at single records. Then you limit to one record without an `ORDER BY` clause, so of all records found you pick one arbitrarily.

Query 2:

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, min(MatchDate)
FROM Matches 
WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND DATE(MatchDate) >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE())
```

You select all records `WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR (AwayTeamID = 1 AND DATE(MatchDate) >= CURRENT_DATE())`. Then you select `min(MatchDate)` of all these records. One row (or zero) will be returned, because you aggregate over all rows (no `GROUP BY` clause). You also select `ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID`. This is invalid, because you are aggregating, so which ID, which home and away teams of the found records should be shown? Depending on session settings, MySQL lets this slip and picks one `ID`, one `HomeTeamID` and on `AwayTeamID` arbitrarily or throws an error (as it should).

Comment: Thanks for the very elaborate answer. This has helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY MatchDate DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

try this

OR

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY MatchDate ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Nearest Date View

```
SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate > CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY MatchDate DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: This code seems to be working, however, when I change a date around it doesn't show that one. It will only ever show the latest row.

Comment: MatchDate field set order by desc

Comment: Code doesn't work as it should. Instead of showing me the first occurance of the date in the future, it will always ouput the latest row.

Comment: i can't unstandard what you like output plz explain

Comment: SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime   FROM Matches WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY MatchDate ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1

Comment: The output should be 1 row ID, where the filter that has to be applied is that it should be the nearest date to now, but not in the past.

Comment: SELECT ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, MatchDate, MatchTime FROM Matches WHERE HomeTeamID = 1 OR AwayTeamID = 1 AND MatchDate > CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY MatchDate DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1

this query is current nearest date to now view